# Why is accessing session state and HttpContext in WebAPI considered bad design?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have several .asmx web services that I want to upgrade to WebAPI. These web services look somewhat like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TheWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
   public string SomeMethod(string SomeInput)
   {
       MySessionModel TheSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] as MySessionModel;

       return SomeClass.SomeMethod(SomeInput, TheSession);
   }
}
```

Basically, I have a single-page application. I'm using Forms Auth to login and redirect users to their "profile" and then, from this page, the app uses web services to communicate with the server. The web services only return raw strings so I don't need serialization at teh web service level. For the moment, the app is hosted in IIS and soon I'll be deploying it into azure.

I've looked around on the web, and several posts suggest that using session state and HttpContext is bad design. Why is using `HttpCurrent` and session state a bad idea in this case?

Comment: Since session are by default stored in memory, then if you are running on multiple computers with load balancing, you'll have a problem since memory isn't copied from one computer to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing innately wrong with using ASP.NET Session, as long as you don't use it as a catch-all basket for any old data. Shopping carts, for example, do not belong in Session: they belong in a Shopping Cart persistence component.

Also, and I suspect the reason for the Azure tag on this question, if you are running in a load-balanced environment such as an Azure Cloud Service, you need to use an external session provider such as a SQL Database or a shared cache. Using the in-process session provider (the default) will cause very odd, often unreproducable bugs as users are switched between different servers with different copies of the session.

As for HttpContext.Current, well, for Web API, things like Inversion of Control, Dependency Injection, and simple testability are important. A clean, testable Web API version of that service might look something like this:

```
public class TheWebService : ApiController {

    private readonly IUserSession _userSession;

    public TheWebService(IUserSession userSession)
    {
        _userSession = userSession;
    }
    public string SomeMethod(string SomeInput)
    {
        MySessionModel TheSession = _userSession.Get();
        return SomeClass.SomeMethod(SomeInput, TheSession);
    }
}

public interface IUserSession
{
    MySessionModel Get();
}
```

You could still *use* `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"]` in a class like this:

```
public class CurrentContextUserSession : IUserSession
{
    public MySessionModel Get()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] as MySessionModel;
    }
}
```

You would then use an IoC container such as Unity or Ninject to set `CurrentContextUserSession` as the implementation of `IUserSession` for Web API to use when constructing instances of `TheWebService`. But when you were writing your tests, you could use a mock or stub implementation of IUserSession that had no dependency on `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, you are using the Session only inside the WebMethod, which is fine as it is already coupled to ASP.NET but many people tend to use this at other layers of their application which is a really bad design.

Common problems of using HttpContext.Current in those layers are:

1. the code cannot be easily unit tested in isolation
2. the code is tightly coupled to an ASP.NET context

This being said, having stateful services that depend on the session is bad design. In the example you have shown, that's an ASMX WebService which is depending on the ASP.NET Session state meaning that the client should be passing cookies around in order to invoke this *service*. Also stateful services are harder to scale.

Comment: The example I'm showing uses asmx and the of the project I'm working on consists of upgrading to WebAPI. I'm only using the web services to pass the incoming request string and the session to a class. Will this architecture cause problems later?

Comment: It's fine since your class doesn't depend on the session. The problem is that this service depends on the session. That's the most fundamental architectural problem it has. It makes it stateful.

Comment: The page is user-specific so I don't see how else to implement the web services without using session state.

Comment: The fact that a page is user-specific has strictly nothing to do with the session. You could perfectly fine have used Forms Authentication to authenticate your users and never rely on any session. There are many, many alternative designs depending on the specific requirements of the application. The worst is to depend on an ASP.NET session.

Comment: I'm already using FormsAuth to secure access to the page. How can I implement a user-specific web service without relying on session state?

Comment: This would very much depend on the specific details about this service. For example `SPA` applications (which is what you seem to be doing) are usually holding their *state* on the client and only calling **STATELESS** services on the server when necessary. Have you looked at some of the popular javascript frameworks like KnockoutJS or AngularJS? The entire state of the application is on the client. On the server you only have lightweight stateless services that are returning some data from the backends.

Comment: Well the bulk of the client data is indeed stored in the client; the custom session object I'm using has just 3 strings and an int. Let's say that the client requests some data from the server via these web services; for now, I'm using session state and is doing so going to be a problem later that would be better be addresses now that I'm upgrading from .asmx to WebAPI?

Comment: Yes, it will be a problem. In ASP.NET Web API there's no such notion as ASP.NET Session. You could of course still do the horrible `HttpContext.Current` thing but that will break if you decide to host your Web API somewhere else than an ASP.NET application. Also if you decide to use OWIN. Not to mention the horror that awaits you if you decide to host your application in a web-farm with multiple nodes.